# Is there any way to change how PickerView looks like?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I meant, how to make PickerView looks not like a cylinder, but more like comboBox in Visual Studio? (Xcode)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is almost impossible to change `UIPickerView`'s appearance, use a `UITableView` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  custom  UIPickerView's ,not like cylinder and other form also , look at this link . this link have some example may be helpful for you 
[link](http://code4app.net/category/picker)